# Running .vbs script file in asp.net using process class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to run a vbscript file in my asp.net application. This vbscript file generate a pdf and store it in specified location. I used process class and give the command it is working fine but when i host the application in IIS 7.0 it is not working rather it does not give any error too. I am using admin user.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

the user of the current appPool in iis should have execute right. this user by default is ApplicationPoolIdentity, it is not your windows account that you logged in. try to change it to your windows account which have admin access.